# GCP Bigtable Python Client lost connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm running into an issue with GCP Bigtable Python Client that it occasionally lost connection with Bigtable and causes a server error.

The error message is attached below. This one happens when I was trying to write to Bigtable. I also observed that when the server has been inactive for a while, this issue tends to happen more often.

```
_Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, Endpoint read failed)>
    at _end_unary_response_blocking (/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py:455)
    at __call__ (/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py:507)
    at commit (/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigtable/row.py:417)
    at send (/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/happybase/batch.py:113)
    at __exit__ (/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/happybase/batch.py:275)
    at put (/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/happybase/table.py:435)
    at write_row (/home/vmagent/app/app/v0/helpers/bigtable_util.py:26)
    at get_current_user (/home/vmagent/app/app/v0/controllers/controller.py:98)
    at dispatch_request (/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1598)
    at full_dispatch_request (/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1612)
    at handle_user_exception (/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1517)
    at wrapped_function (/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py:161)
    at full_dispatch_request (/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1614)
    at wsgi_app (/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1982)
```

Have anyone had similar experience? Is this a know bug in Bigtable Python Client?

Comment: Your best bet is to ask the question here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python

Comment: This looks very similar to github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/2683

Comment: It is. I already post my finding in the issue. So far the ticket is still opeb

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this has been fixed in https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/2683.

Given this is a very old question, I assume the newer releases should already fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So far my solution for handling this is to put a manual retry when it fails. It worked for us since the issue doesn't occur frequently. Also, it seems to be less of an issue in version 0.28.1